# How to evaluate a SQL function result and query from nested SELECT

Tags: sql, select, aggregate-functions, ormlite

How can I implement this SQL query in ORMLite and evaluate the result?

```
SELECT SUM(column1 * column2) AS total FROM (ANOTHER_SELECT_QUERY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple different ways to do this.  One way would be the simple:

```
long sum = dao.queryRawValue(
        "SELECT SUM(column1 * column2) AS total FROM (...)");
```

You can use the `QueryBuilder` to build the query.

```
QueryBuilder<Foo, Integer> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
qb.selectRaw("SUM(column1 * column2) AS total");
qb.where()...
long sum = dao.queryRawValue(qb.prepareStatementString());
```

I don't think you need to have the inner since `column1` and `column2` I assume are in the inner query and the `WHERE` can be just moved to the outer query.

Comment: I can not leave away the inner query as I got a GROUP BY statement in there and that would lead to a wrong SUM functionality. But I could sum up the result manually in code as I have a list of the inner query's results anyway. I assume there is no functionality for inner queries in ORMLite, am I right?